# Pygame rectangle isn't being drawn

Tags: python, pygame

When I run the code, it does not show any error. The rectangle just doesn't appear. How can that be fixed?

The function responsible is `render()` with the line `pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (100, 100, 50, 50))`.

```
import pygame

w, h = 1000, 600
caption = "Game"
background = (255, 255, 255)
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

win = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
pygame.display.set_caption(caption)


def start():
    # This function runs only once at the start of the game
    pass


def logic():
    # This function runs every frame. This function contains the game's logic.
    pass


def render():
    # This function runs every frame. This function contains code for drawing
    # everything to the screen.
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (100, 100, 50, 50))


def main():
    global running
    start()

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        logic()
        win.fill(background)
        render()
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Comment: Which Python version do you use ? This code is working for me, Python version 3.6.8

Comment: Works for me as well with pygame version 1.9.6 and Python 3.7.3

Comment: Since your code seems fine but doesnt work for you I guess you use macOS. If that's the case then you'll find other questions with similiar problems on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering everyone. I was using Atom to write and run this code but every time I used to run this code in Atom, using `script` package, it used to show a blank screen. Solution is to use `build-python` package (its a package that works, unlike `script`) instead. Sorry, I should’ve been more specific.